# how to write Custom query in laravel 5.7?

Tags: php

I want to update my column with this query , so how make custom query ini laravel

```
UPDATE 
    tb_antrian 
SET 
    jam = DATE_ADD(TIME(jam), INTERVAL -? MINUTE) 
WHERE 
    id > ? 
AND 
    date(jam) = ?
```

Comment: I tried this on Google, maybe this can help you? https://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries

Answer (score 0):

You can use raw queries with `DB::statement` like below:

```
DB::statement("UPDATE tb_antrian SET jam = DATE_ADD(TIME(jam), INTERVAL -? MINUTE) WHERE id > ? AND date(jam) = ?");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me you can try it as below.

DB::update('UPDATE tb_antrian SET jam = DATE_ADD(TIME(jam), INTERVAL -? MINUTE) WHERE id > ? AND date(jam) = ?');